# JQuery url construction trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, web, get

I am trying to load a website into a div (`div.content`).

The website requires a login via a POST.

The javascript tries to load the site, detects the redirect to the login form, POSTs the username and password and finally reloads the url since authentication was succesful.

Now the problem is that the url is not constructed correctly. The url should be like this :

```
https://mysite.com/WebUntis/index.do?school=schoolname#Timetable?
onlyTimetable=true&ajaxCommand=renderTimetable&date=20130418&type=1&id=17
&formatId=2&departmentId=-1&buildingId=-1
```

but the jquery builds it like this:

```
https://mysite.com/WebUntis/index.do?
onlyTimetable=true&ajaxCommand=renderTimetable&date=20130418&type=1&id=17
&formatId=2&departmentId=-1&buildingId=-1.
```

Can somebody help me out here? I checked the syntax by looking at a lot of examples, but I am unable to find the fix.

```
function openUrl()
{
  jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'https://mysite.com/WebUntis/index.do?school=schoolname#Timetable?',
   type:'GET',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: {
      //school: 'schoolname',
      ajaxCommand: 'renderTimetable',
      onlyTimetable: 'true',
      date: '20130418',
      type: '1',
      id: '17',
      formatId: '2',
      departmentId: '-1',
      buildingId: '-1'
   },
   success: function(result) {
      var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
      if(html.find("form").attr("id") == "login")//login form found
      {
          alert("Trying to login...");
          login(); //This just POSTs a username and password
      };
      $('div.content').html(result);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: what is the `#` doing there

Comment: Looks like the only problem is the `school` parameter, you could url encode it and try

Comment: I suspect you are confusing the jQuery url constructor by having two question marks in the URL.  "..?school=schoolname#Timetable?..".  Did you mean to have an ampersand (&) after timetable?

Comment: well to be honest, I dont really know why there are two question marks. It is an external website. But that is the only url which seems to work...

Comment: A correction to my previous comment:   The hash causes the issue in jQuery 2.0.  The following comment is from the jQuery 2.0 source and occurs near the start of the ajax function.  "// Remove hash character (#7531: and string promotion)"

Comment: I tried changing this line: 
`s.url = ( ( url || s.url || ajaxLocation ) + "" ).replace( rhash, "" )` to this one: `s.url = ( ( url || s.url || ajaxLocation ) + "" ).replace( rhash, "#" )` , however, still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the parameter `school`

```
function openUrl()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://mysite.com/WebUntis/index.do',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            school: encodeURIComponent('schoolname#Timetable?'),
            ajaxCommand: 'renderTimetable',
            onlyTimetable: 'true',
            date: '20130418',
            type: '1',
            id: '17',
            formatId: '2',
            departmentId: '-1',
            buildingId: '-1'
        },
        success: function(result) {
            var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);
            if(html.find("form").attr("id") == "login")//login form found
            {
                alert("Trying to login...");
                login(); //This just POSTs a username and password
            };
            $('div.content').html(result);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! This gives a 'invalid school name' error unfortunately...